# Laravel, Cannot get user details in auth.basic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried this in `routes/web.php` but the result is `null`

```
Route::get('swagger-yaml', function () {
    dd(auth()->user());
})
->middleware(['auth.basic:web'])
```

**Update**

I found the reason of the strange behaviour, that's because in `config/auth.php` I have:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard'     => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

But how can I fix that? For a series of reasons cannot change `config/auth.php`.

Comment: `web` middleware is already added in `web.php` file. why are you adding?

Comment: try with remove `:web` from middleware.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya yest but it doesn't work because my default guard in config/auth.php is `api`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this

```
Auth::user();
```

instead of

```
auth()->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this:

```
Route::get('swagger-yaml', function () {
    dd(Auth::user());
})->middleware('auth.basic');
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by adding `config(['auth.defaults.guard' => 'web']);` like this:

```
Route::get('swagger-yaml', function () {
    config(['auth.defaults.guard' => 'web']);
    dd(auth()->user());
})
->middleware(['auth.basic:web'])
```